# Add a jar file to another jar file

Tags: java, mysql, jar

In my project I have this code that tell class loader to load `Driver.class` like so:

```
Class.forName(org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver);
```

In Eclipse it runs with no problems and I have created the Jar file of the project. But I don't know how to insert the

`mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar`

into a Jar file of my project. The folder structure look like this: [image: this]

MANIFEST file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: server.MultiServer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you finally just want to run your code as

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

There are two options.

1. Keep mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar next to your jar in the same folder and add classpath: mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar to the manifest.
2. Copy all the classes in mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar to your jar. Do not copy the jar but the classes in the jar. This is called a fat jar or uber jar. You can automate the same using maven shade plugin.

Answer (score -1):

When you invoke your application jar add the -cp or -classpath option and provide the path to the dependent libraries, here the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar`.

for example refer the below example

`java -jar -classpath C:\myproject\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar myproject.jar`

Comment: You must use either `-jar` or `-classpath`, you can't combine the two. The classpath will be ignored if you do.